# Angular project hosted in gh-pages can not find files and displays blank page

Tags: angular, github-pages

I built an Angular project running the `ng build` command, and locally it works perfectly.

I uploaded the content of the dist folder to a repository in Github and created its GitHub Page, however, it does not render anything. Looking at the console, it throws errors saying that it can't find any of the bundle files.

[image: The browser trying to find these files outside the repository]

Why isn't it looking the files in the folder where is the repository but outside?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post link for github repo?

Comment: Sure! here it is: https://github.com/jcrr1985/tutenTestD

Comment: I am not seeing gh-pages branch there. Post the link where the gh-pages branch is present.

Comment: there you go:
https://jcrr1985.github.io/tutenTestD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `base href` of your `index.html`.

Add your github pages url to `base href`

`<base href="https://jcrr1985.github.io/tutenTestD/">`

I have forked your github and now its working fine. Check `index.html`.

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Tuten</title> 
    <base href="https://jcrr1985.github.io/tutenTestD/"> <!-- changes here -->

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>

</html>
```